# Need help in showing that $\lim_{Δx\to 0}\frac{a^{Δx}-1}{Δx}=\ln(a)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

Defining $$e^x=\lim_{n\to0}(1+nx)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ and $$e^y=x ;y=lnx $$ I want to show that $e$ is the unique number such that $\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$. I eventually obtain the expression $$\frac{da^x}{dx}=C(a)\cdot a^x$$ where $$C(a)=\lim_{Δx\to 0}\frac{a^{Δx}-1}{Δx}$$

Beyond this point, I am unable to show that $C(a)$ is infact $ln(a)$. One method that seems to work is to ignore **"$\lim_{Δx\to0}$"** , make $a^{Δx}$ the subject and then restore the limit operator to obtain $$a=\lim_{Δx\to0}(1+C(a)\cdotΔx)^{\frac{1}{Δx}}\Rightarrow a=e^{C(a)}\Rightarrow C(a)=\ln(a)$$but simply ignoring the limit operator feels extremely wrong. Could someone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\eta=a^{\delta x}-1$.

$$\lim_{\delta x\to0}\frac{a^{\delta x}-1}{\delta x}=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\frac{\eta}{\log_a(\eta+1)}=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\eta}\log_a(\eta+1)}=\cdots$$

You can go from here. I'll edit in a full answer if you wish.

Hints: consider what $\eta$ tends to as $\delta x\to0$, and remember your log properties!